# Edubuntu Offline Package

Tags: 14.04, offline, edubuntu

Is there any offline (.deb) installer for "Educational Desktop for Ubuntu"? 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64

I have some problem with internet connection. An offline installer would help me :D

Comment: You'll want to look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) question, since there are many packages related to Edubuntu. EDIT: Never mind; that's out of development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a miror link

```
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04/release/
```

download the iso image burn or boot from usb & install it easly & offline

Comment: but i'll lose all my current stuff.

Comment: when you install it dont choose replace current linux version 
choose upgrade it